# What are these black plastic things

Tags: hardware

I just bought my first [server case](http://www.logic-case.com/products/rackmount-chassis/3u/3u-standard-chassis-14-x-35-hdd-sc-39650g-atx/) (Yay  me). With it came a box full of these plastic things that I have no idea what they are for or what they are called. There are twenty of these things in total.

[image: Box of twenty plastic things]

Comment: Didn't the manual explain what to do with those?

Comment: Its a cheap [3U Case](http://www.logic-case.com/products/rackmount-chassis/3u/3u-standard-chassis-14-x-35-hdd-sc-39650g-atx/) that didn't come with a manual and its product page doesn't mention them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are drive rails which you attach to a drive to slide into a drive slot.